# Sleep built in keyword pauses the spawned process

Tags: robotframework

I am using Process Library in Robot Framework to spawn a process(a bash shell is spawned to execute the required process) to prepare runtime environment for test cases. But when I use Sleep keyword in my robot files, the spawned process is also become paused. How can I avoid this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the cause of this problem. It is not related with the process.

Answer (score -1):

You can try keyword **Wait For Process** https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Process.html#Wait%20For%20Process

Comment: This is not applicable to my situation since the spawned process needs to run until test suite is finished.